# has no member named

Tags: c++

This is header file name monitor.h

```
class DSRAgent;
class Detector;
class ReputationSystem;

class Monitor {
public:
    Monitor();
    Monitor(DSRAgent* agent);
    void handleTap(const Packet* packet);
    void handlePublishInfo(nsaddr_t src, double identification, int count,rating* ratings);
    void handlePacketSent(Packet* packet);
    void publishInfo(map<nsaddr_t, rating*> ratings);
    void setNetID(nsaddr_t netid); 
    nsaddr_t getNetID();
    friend class PackTableTimer;
    void setReputationSystem(ReputationSystem* rep_system);
    bool isPACK(int uid);
    void Terminate();

    PackTableTimer* pack_table_timer;

private:
    void packTableCheck();
    map<nsaddr_t, double> published_ids;
    PackTable pack_t;
    DSRAgent* dsragent;
    Detector* detector;
    ReputationSystem* reputation_system;
    nsaddr_t net_id; 
};
class PackTableTimer : public TimerHandler {
public:
PackTableTimer(Monitor *a) : TimerHandler() { a_ = a;}
void expire(Event *e);
protected:
Monitor *a_;
};
```

the other file that is monitor.cc

```
void PackTableTimer::expire(Event *e)
{
    a_->packTableCheck();
    resched(PACK_TIMEOUT + PACK_TIMEOUT * Random::uniform(1.0));
}

DSRAgent* dsragent;

Monitor::Monitor(DSRAgent* agent)
{ 
    this->dsragent = agent;
    this->detector = new Detector(this);
    pack_table_timer = new PackTableTimer(this);
    pack_table_timer->sched(PACK_TIMEOUT + PACK_TIMEOUT * Random::uniform(1.0));
}

void Monitor::handleTap(const Packet* packet)
{
    Behavior behavior;
    hdr_sr *srh = hdr_sr::access(packet);
    hdr_ip *iph = hdr_ip::access(packet);
    hdr_cmn *cmh = hdr_cmn::access(packet);
    ID cur_hop(srh->addrs()[srh->cur_addr()-1]);
    nsaddr_t cur_addr = cur_hop.getNSAddr_t();
    int uid = cmh->uid();
    map<int, PackData*>::iterator it;
    it = pack_t.find(uid);
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
**monitor.h: error: ‘PackTableTimer’ does not name a type

monitor.cc: In constructor ‘Monitor::Monitor(DSRAgent*)’

monitor.cc: error: ‘class Monitor’ has no member named ‘PackTableTimer’

monitor.cc: error: ‘pack_table_timer’ was not declared in this scope**
```

Comment: @user2214138 Don't ask questions for people to fix your compile errors please. The questions are of no use to others. Read documentation or ask a more general question if you don't understand how to fix things given the compiler's helpful message to you, so that other people can learn from the answers given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to forward-declare `PackTableTimer` before you can use it in `monitor.h`

Put this with your other forward-declarations.

```
class PackTableTimer;
```

Comment: but that generates another error of        expected ) before * token that is why have declared it lately

Comment: You'll have to give more of the error message for me to know what that means. I mean that you should forward-declare it before `Monitor`, and then define it afterwards (as you currently do). It must be declared before it can be used in `Monitor`, but it can be defined afterwards.

Comment: monitor.h: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token the error is in this line PackTableTimer(Monitor *a) : TimerHandler() { a_ = a;}

Comment: To clarify, what did you change? You should have, in this order: 1. a forward declaration of `PackTableTimer` (that is, the line that appears in my answer), 2. the other forward declarations, 3. the definition of class `Monitor`, 4. the definition of class `PackTableTimer`. The only change from the source in your question is the addition of the line in my answer near the top of the file.

Comment: yes sir u got that right that resolved my error

Answer (score 1):

You miss declaration of PackTableTimer class.

Comment: have a look again i have declared it now